# Is it possible to extend TestCafe Studio?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, extensibility

I am looking to extend the studio IDE and add custom on-page-actions or assertions. The goal is to enable non-technical team members to write more robust tests without writing any code.

I know custom scripts can be written, but I want a first-class experience where the user simply clicks the icon and drags it into place.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IDE is not extensible in the manner you described at the moment.

Comment: Thanks. Is the IDE open source or are there any plans to add that kind of functionality?

Comment: The IDE is a commercial product. There are no plans for such functionality at the moment.